# Is there any Bitbucket API that can give the list of commits of a user without specifying a project or branch?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I am trying to get all commits of a user in Bitbucket. I couldn't find any documentation related to it. I was wondering if anybody else had the same use case.

I am looking for something like this:

`https://BB_URL/rest/api/1.0/user/commits`

Comment: Try this one.  `/teams/{user-id}/search/code` https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-other-operations/#api-teams-username-search-code-get

Comment: @JeremyFiel Thanks for the response. I tried it but I've no access somehow. Maybe because I'm using Basic Auth. I'm not using OAUTH to get to the rest api.